# How to download a http file in unix that required login befor downloading?

Tags: unix, download, w3m

I would like to download file from a website that required login prior to downloading. I tried w3p and I can open it but I don't how how to download it. What I tried is:

```
w3m https://services.appliedgenomics.org/sequences-export/536-RNA-seq_Disco_TuDO/
```

then I give my user name and passward to go in to directory where my desired file is and open it.

Now file is open how can I download it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use curl to login and download a file.

syntax

```
curl -u username:password http://example.com
```

you can also specify download location using `-o` option.

```
curl -o ~/Desktop/myfile.pdf http://url-to-file/abcedfeghijklmnop.pdf
```

This page has good tutorial on the usage of curl

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/curl-download-file-example-under-linux-unix/